# What are the available values for workspaceElement state in CLI Hooks?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, cli

Looking at the [doc for CLI Hooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_plugins.meta/sfdx_cli_plugins/cli_plugins_customize_hooks_list.htm?search_text=workspaceElements), some hook types like `predeploy` and `postsourceupdate` return a `workspaceElement`.

This element contains a `state` property that contains only one character, that I assume means the following:

- c: changed
- d: deleted
- n: new

Is this documented anywhere ?
I assume that having this documented would make sense.
I would be sure not to miss any value, and having a documentation would make it less prone to be changed without notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Source code, you can view [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforce-alm/blob/master/src/lib/source/sourceState.ts)

The state field maps to one of these, It's the state of the local file when force source pull or push occurs.

- UNCHANGED: 'u'
- CHANGED: 'c'
- DELETED: 'd'
- NEW: 'n'
- DUP: 'p'

The DUP can be generated when mdapi covert happens and two files with the same name exist. The documented use case is discussed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_convert_mdapi.htm)

This is not documented and can be improved. Will Share the feedback internally.

The source code will go open source and these flags will become obvious then.

Comment: Thank you Mohith ! :)